# how transfer videos from within an App to the mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, data-transfer

I would like to know, if their is a way to transfer videos from Coursera-App on the ipad to the mac (without re-download them from the internet)?

I tried to connect the ipad through iTunes, to see if i can get the content of the app, but it seemed that I cannot get to the media inside the apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app such as [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to copy the files over USB from the app's container.
iTunes File Sharing only works if the app in question supports this.